# Sequential Algorithm to generate Fractal (Koch's snowflake)

Tags: algorithms, recursive-algorithms, fractals

As part of an assignment I had developed a sequential algorithm to generate a Koch's snowflake. Algorithm I have encountered so far have been recursive and iterations generate closer approximations. The algorithm I made can generate nth iteration directly and requires a memory of two Vertices while for the normal algorithm's e need all the vertices from (n-1) iteration to get the nth iteration. How relevant is such a sequential algorithm? Can I publish it?